# AWS EC2 Instance can't be reached even though docker containers running

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

i'm trying to get my laravel app running in ec2 with docker containers. I have two containers one of the app and then one for nginx. I have created the ec2 instance with `docker-machine` and i've also built the docker images successfully.

Running `docker-compose up` also runs successfully. If I run `docker ps` I see the two containers running.

So I have two containers running I would expect to go to the http://ec2-ip-addy-here.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ and see the app. My hunch is that something isn't setup on AWS side correctly, maybe the VPC? I'm a novice with AWS so I don't know what to look for. Any ideas?

I'm following this guide https://hackernoon.com/stop-deploying-laravel-manually-steal-this-docker-configuration-instead-da9ecf24cd2e

I'm also using the [laradock nginx dockerfile](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/nginx/Dockerfile) and my own dockerfile for the app

EDIT:
It could be the networks that are created with docker-compose. I say that because I just checked and the network is being prepended with the service name. When I run `docker network ls` I see a network called php-fpm_backend. Here's my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

services:
### PHP-FPM ##############################################
    php-fpm:
      image: php-fpm
      container_name: php-fpm
      build:
        context: ../
        dockerfile: ./laradock/php-fpm/Dockerfile-Prod
        args:
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=7.2
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=true
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=true
          - INSTALL_POSTGIS=true
      expose:
        - "9000"
      networks:
        - backend

### NGINX Server #########################################
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      container_name: nginx
      build:
        context: ../
        dockerfile: ./laradock/nginx/Dockerfile-Prod
        args:
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm
      networks:
        - backend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. It was as I thought, I had to add a new security group with port 80/443 access for HTTP and HTTPS.